# dynamic textview display in android

Tags: android, textview

In my application I am showing list of datas from database in a list view.For that listview i have 1 header with 4 text views arranged horizontally..But i want this to be arranged with some space exactly between and also it should fit into every screen. Please help me.Thanks in advance.By the following code it is arranging 1 after the other without space.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#ffffffff">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdate"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="Date"/> 

      <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdateasc"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"           
        />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdes"     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="Item"
        />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/hdritemasc"     
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

      <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrprice"      
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="Price"
        />      

       <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrpriceasc"      
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

      <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrtot"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:text="Total"
        />

       <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrtotasc"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use layout margin for spacing between view like

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

To fit them on the screen you can use layout_weight.Give every view weight 1 so all will be equal.You already use fill_parent for the width of your LinearLayout.

`android:layout_weight="1"` for every view

Comment: Thanks Rasel..But if i am using this 5 r 10 dp means then how it will impact screen with different sizes.

Comment: S Rassel..Now i put that and its fit into the emulator in which i am working..I have no other screen size devices,so only i am asking whether by doing so it will fit for every screen..

Comment: K thanks Rasel....\Wait i will accept ur answer..because there is some time limit to accept..

Answer (score 0):

try this use  `android:layout_weight="1"`in all `TextView`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="#ffffffff">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdate"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1"       
      android:textColor="#ff00ff00"     
    android:text="Date"/> 

  <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdateasc"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:text="gffgfg"  
       android:textColor="#ffff0000"     
     android:layout_weight="1"             
    />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdes"     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
     android:layout_weight="1"   
     android:textColor="#FF4500"       
    android:text="Item"
    />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/hdritemasc"     
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="gdgdfgsg"
       android:textColor="#ff0000ff"     
     android:layout_weight="1"     

    />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrprice"   
       android:layout_weight="1"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:textColor="#ff00ff00"     
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="Price"
    />      
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrap_content for widht you should use weight on your textview and weightsum on linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:weightSum="100.0">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdate"        
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="100/number of text views"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"      
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"     
        android:text="Date"/> 
        ....
</LinearLayout>
```

If you do not want to use exact values for your margins you should add some blank text views and set the weight smaller than the one of the ones in which you have text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="#ffffffff">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdate" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Date" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdateasc" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrdes" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Item" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdritemasc" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrprice" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Price" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrpriceasc" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000000" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrtot" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Total" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/hdrtotasc" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Let me know if it is done or not. It should work. And if this answer help you out, accept it.